# Where are Unity and Unreal Engine 4 installation files downloaded to?

Tags: installation, unity3d

Forgive me if this question sounds trivial, but I have tried Google many times and it failed to return any relevant results.

The thing is very simple, I have installed Unity (via Unity Hub) and Unreal Engine 4 (via Epic Games Launcher), the installations were successful and I haven't encountered any problems and I don't want to uninstall them, but they downloaded tens of gigabytes installation files that are obviously useless after installation, but they still occupy precious system drive space, so I want to remove the installation files and save space.

But I can't find where the files are, I have tried Google, and Google had once again proved its uselessness;

So I searched for the folders using PowerShell:

```powershell
$env:Programdata,$env:Userprofile | %{get-childitem -path $_ -force -directory -recurse -depth 5 | where {$_.name -match 'unity|epic|unreal'} | %{$_.fullname}}
```

And after removing irrelevant results and the installation directories of the programs, the result is this:

```powershell
C:\ProgramData\Epic
C:\ProgramData\Unity
C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\EpicGamesLauncher
C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\Unity
C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\unityhub-updater
C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\UnrealEngine
C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\UnrealEngineLauncher
C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\LocalLow\Unity
C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Roaming\Unity
C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Roaming\Unity Hub
C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Roaming\UnityHub
```

But they only take up less than 2GiB space:

```powershell
$size=@()
$folders=@(
'C:\ProgramData\Epic'
'C:\ProgramData\Unity'
'C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\EpicGamesLauncher'
'C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\Unity'
'C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\unityhub-updater'
'C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\UnrealEngine'
'C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\UnrealEngineLauncher'
'C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\LocalLow\Unity'
'C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Roaming\Unity'
'C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Roaming\Unity Hub'
'C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Roaming\UnityHub'
)
$folders | %{$size+=(Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Force -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum / 1048576}
($size | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
```

The final line returns 1067.47400283813 which means they collectively only occupy 1067.47400283813MiB space, but the online installers downloaded tens of gibibytes of files, so where are the files downloaded to, so that I can remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found out the answer!

I just opened `procmon` and reran the installations just to find out where were the files downloaded to.

For Unity, I opened Unity Hub and found that the installed version was 2019-something LTS while the latest is 2021.1.0f1, so I uninstalled the outdated version and installed the latest version while `procmon` is up, I set the filter `ProcessName is Unity Hub.exe then Include`, and discovered the files are downloaded to a folder inside %temp% (%localappdata%\temp) named unityhub-something, mine was `C:\Users\Estranger\AppData\Local\Temp\unityhub-c7018100-8fb1-11eb-a1e6-938f25040bc4`, its contents:

[image]

The files were packaged installation archives and they were automatically deleted after the installation was complete.

For Unreal Engine 4 the already installed version is the latest which is 4.26.1, I clicked Library→plus sign and started the installation process of 4.25.4, I added `ProcessName is EpicGamesLauncher.exe then Include` filter to `procmon` and this is what I found:

[image]

So there is no single package archived installer of UE4, the files are not compressed together but instead they are downloaded individually and written directly to the installation directory so there is nothing to remove.